# How to fix URIBuilder getRequest param escaping

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

in my Code I want to start a GET Request on a SugarCRM REST API V10, for a filter i have to add some parameters to the request

what should be:

```
https://domain/rest/v10/Accounts?filter=[{"system_uuid_c":"f937456c-fdac-4d90-b1ca-ba31d4eb2922"}]
```

what comes out:

```
https://domain/rest/v10/Accounts?filter%3D=%5B%7B%22system_uuid_c%22%3A%22f937456c-fdac-4d90-b1ca-ba31d4eb2922%22%7D%5D
```

My Code:

```
    filter = filter.concat("[{");
    filter = filter.concat("\"system_uuid_c");
    filter = filter.concat("\":");
    filter = filter.concat("\"");
    filter = filter.concat(system_uuid);
    filter = filter.concat("\"}]");

    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(HOST + PATH);
            builder.addParameter("filter", filter);
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(builder.build());
```

The `"` are important for the filter.

Comment: I suspect a typo: replace `builder.addParameter("filter=", filter);` with `builder.addParameter("filter", filter);`
The character replacements look quite legit.

Comment: I tried it also this way but nothing changed, i correct my post :)

Comment: Sure nothing changed? The url changes to `...?filter=%5B...`, isn't it?
Tested here: if I do '`URI x = builder.build(); System.out.println(x.getQuery());` the query part is perfectly formatted.
Did you test on the server or only 'visually'? The replacement of any special characters in the query part are essential.

Comment: @user3328547 Actually, the URL is valid and has the value you want. The server will receive/parse the value correctly. What is the problem you get? What is the receiving end doing with the data/URI/URL? Are there any errors and if yes, what are the errors? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

The URL works. I got an error while the objectMapper tried to convert the result String to an object. So everything is fine :)

Thank you for your help.